# Get query string only if integer

Tags: php

Trying to get a query string into a variable but only if it's an integer.

Code is probably a bit more complicated than it should be but this is where I'm up to-

```
  //get page number. default is 1. check is not empty and is a number      
     if (empty($_GET['pag'])) {$page = 1;}
     else if (is_int($_GET['pag'])){$page = $_GET['pag'];}
     else {$page = 1;}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try is_numeric cause $_GET has string type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) instead - `is_int()` doesn't test to see if a string is a numeric string.

```
if (empty($_GET['pag'])) {$page = 1;}
else if (is_numeric($_GET['pag'])){$page = (int) $_GET['pag'];}
else {$page = 1;}
```

Comment: I've Googled everything and even came across that and for some reason it didn't register with me... Thank you!

Comment: is_numeric will return true for values with a decimal, such as 9.1, which may not be what you want, if you are using these variables to lookup id values from a database table. if this is your situation, try typecasting as int() as shown below

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, type cast the value to an integer:

```
$page = empty($_GET['pag']) ? 1 : (int) $_GET['pag'];
```

Although, if I remember well, type casting something that is not an integer will make it a 0, but you should check anyways if the $page is in between bounds before doing anything with it, because the user might as well type in ?pag0 in your URL.

Answer (score 2):

```
$page = ((isset($_GET['pag']) && is_numeric($_GET['pag'])) ? (int)$_GET['pag'] : 1;
```